# Asking multiple permissions together in same dialog box

Tags: android, android-permissions

Is it possible to ask multiple permissions - say READ_CONTACTS, READ_SMS and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - together in the same Dialog box?

If so, how? Please provide an example.

I have been searching online for it for hours, but can't find a way. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

**No**, Google doesn't allow to ask all the permissions in the same dialog box in fact the dialog boxes are itself created by google. Still, you can use consecutively asking all permissions

Google has made its own library for handling permissions easily check it out
**[Easy Permissions](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions)**

Comment: Does this library enable asking permissions in same dialog box?

Comment: No, It handles the hard part, After Run time permissions have launched in Marshmallow, I have suffered so much managing the whole flow manually, This library only manages the asking of permissions in run time, It is not possible till now to ask permission in the same dialog box

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

`int ALL_PERMISSIONS = 101;`
`final String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};`

Add below code in `onCreate()` method

```
 if (!hasPermissions(LoginActivity.this, permissions)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, ALL_PERMISSIONS);
    }
```

add this method in the same class

```
  public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

don't forget to add these in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE " />`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>`

Comment: I haven't tried this code, but I think this code makes Android ask all permissions consecutively, one by one. What I want is that all permissions should be asked in the same dialog box. How is it possible?