# Android asking for only one of the required permissions

Tags: java, android, permissions

I want to request the following permissions: `VIBRATE,EXTERNAL_STORAGE,INTERNET`.
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64605176/asking-multiple-permissions-together-in-same-dialog-box) StackOverflow answer, this is how I'm asking for the permissions:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int ALL_PERMISSIONS = 101;
    final String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.VIBRATE,Manifest.permission.INTERNET};

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (!hasPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissions)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, ALL_PERMISSIONS);
        }
//Other irrelevant code
}
    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem is my app is requesting only storage permission nothing else.

[image: screenshot]

The `VIBRATE` and `INTERNET` are permissions aren't requested nor granted. How can I ask all the permissions sequentially?

Here is proof that `VIBRATE` and `INTERNET` permissions aren't granted:

[image: permission]

Answer (score 1):

Internet and Vibrate permission is not Required Runtime permission so you just asked these permissions from manifest . if you want to check , go to mobile settings app management and check your application permissions

Comment: I checked my mobile app permissions , the vibrate and internet permissions aren't visible. You can check the screenshot that I've recently uploaded.

Comment: Those aren't listed, they get granted